# How to center fit image in linear layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, image-scaling

I have an xml screen with  three children linear layouts in a parent linear layout of vertical orientation.  First child contains an image view and when running the application I can not view any image. Why? is the image size too big?? If so.. how to scale it? However Image is view able in my design tab. of android stdudio.  Below is my complete code for xml file.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_sign_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.root.my_laoder.SignUp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ty"
       />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"


        >


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

           />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"

            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        >

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"

        />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your ImageView do `wrap_content` for both `height and width`.

Comment: I did that and I also tried doing  scaletype check my edited code.. No results :(

Comment: if you can provide a snapshot it would be more easy for me. Also to centre fit your image you have to put `android:gravity="centre_vertical|centre_horizontal"` in the linear layout containing imageview

Comment: does changing the image work? or different scaletypes (fitCenter) ? try changing the imageView height to wrap_content too (if not you will push the rest of your views out of the screen)

Comment: https://imagebin.ca/v/3L6C3tyxYASY @jack jay I have shown you the design tab. i dont know why my mobile application is showing white space instead of  this logo.

Comment: can you please upload @drawable/ty ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** Add attribute `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to `LinearLayout`, to show `ImageView` in center.

**2.** Update `ImageView` width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and remove attribute `android:layout_gravity="center"`.

**3.** Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` instead of `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_sign_up"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ty" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: suppose this ibm image is a big image.. Will that be centered this way? adjusting in screen?

Comment: I guess this solved the problem but my app crashes on load saying out of memory issue. My image is too big I guess. How to handle this? can you tell???PLease

Comment: You can use Glide or Picasso to load large image. or use small image as its your logo no need to use large image. I have used 500 * 400 image

Comment: Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/  and Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide  .... both are very easy to use and can handle large image smoothly

Answer (score 0):

what are the dimens values for these parameters?

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

and why you are using separate linearlayout for imageView even with parent layout as linear?

kindly remove that

have you checked the size of image you are using as a background in ImageView? if size is large than probably image is pushing your rest of your views out of the screen.try to give fixed width and height let's say 100dp for both and see if you are able to see anything.

If you wanna make imageView centre horizontally use in ImagView view

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

above line of code will not work with separate linear layout for ImageView. If you are gonna use separate layout for ImageView anyway, use below line of code inside that linearlayout

android:gravity="center_horizontal"

Note: sorry I'm not able to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your ImageView:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_minus" />
```

Comment: https://imagebin.ca/v/3L6C3tyxYASY this is my design tab view.. but i cant figure out that WHY WHY is my android application showing a white space instead of this logo...  rest of the page is great..  Can you tell?? Look I have used even ur piece of code

Comment: try to give the ImageView a fixed height.

Comment: tried and nothing happened,,   and even if this works. It wont be  a good practice. Second thing is that I even have tried using different images all are working fine.  Just this magical image

Comment: Wow. Can i try this image of my machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed scaleType of ImageView, Follow the steps to make your image center

```
 1. Add attribute android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" to show ImageView in center.

 2. Set ImageView layout_width="match_parent" and 
 layout_height="@dimen/fixed_height"
 ==> height will be fixed but width will automatically adjust 
 according to device size

 3. and set scaleType="fitEnd" or scaleType="fitCenter"
 ==> fitEnd is ( Scale the image from the end of the container ) and 
 possible to have space on top
 if image is different each time.
 ==> fitCenter is (Scale the image from center) and possibility to 
 have space in top and bottom

    Example:
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cover_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fixed_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd" />
```